# Cached partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Model m)
{
    var db = new Db();
    m.Prop = "New Value";
    db.Save(m);

    return PartialView("_ModelForm", m);
}
```

For some reason, although `m` is updated within the controller the `"Old Value"` of `Prop` is returned in the response rather than the `"New Value"`.

I looked at the HTTP-response and the old value is returned as part of the response (the `"New Value"` change is ignored), so the problem is **not** that it is cached on the client.

I tried to decorate  the controller with the OutputCache attribute but with no success.

`db.Save` has no side-effects that alters the `Prop` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ModelState.Clear()`. When your are reposting your View its value is populated from `ModelState`.

```
public ActionResult Save(Model m)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    var db = new Db();
    m.Prop = "New Value";
    db.Save(m);

    return PartialView("_ModelForm", m);
}
```